# Does an indemnification agreement saying it was not induced by improper conduct make sense?

Tags: contract-law, trusts-and-estates, indemnity

I am a beneficiary of a family trust, being forced to sign an indemnification agreement, similar to the situation described in [Why California codified "A trustee may not require a beneficiary to relieve the trustee of liability..."?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33598/why-california-codified-a-trustee-may-not-require-a-beneficiary-to-relieve-the)

The trustee is Bank of America in Florida - unfortunately not in California.

The one-sided 'agreement' includes the statement that I was not induced to sign it by improper conduct of the Trustee. Does this statement have any legal value? What if I was forced by improper conduct to state that I was not forced by improper conduct?

We are 13 beneficiaries all living in Denmark. This makes the legal process quite troublesome. I guess our best remedy in case of excessive administration costs or other problems would be to publicize the case?

Comment: How exactly were you forced to sign the agreement, more so when it contains that *no-coercion* clause? This just complicates your burden of proof that you were actually coerced to sign the agreement.

Comment: @Iñaki. They are withholding the funds from all beneficiaries until all beneficiaries have signed this agreement. Even if I have the patience to fight over this issue, there is a group pressure from the rest of the family to just give in to their pressure and get the money without further trouble.

Comment: The indemnification agreement also requires that we waive all rights to an account of the Trustee's acts and administration expenses, as I understand it.